# Decompress GZIP data from PHP

Tags: php, compression, base64, gzip, chunked

**I've been trying to decompress GZIP data from web server**

**Currently Using:**

- EasyPHP
- Code Igniter
- PHP

**My Problem**

I haven't decompressed the data , it is actually a String compression not a file and i've been searching throughout the net and it only gives me file examples.

**Some of my outputs: I haven't seen errors but i got this output:**

> org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@3e583da8" is this an error on my side? I've been searching this thing and found out that is from java

Here is my PHP method:

```
    $gzdata = gzopen($chunkData,"r");
    $uncompressed_file = fopen($chunkData,"w");
    while($line = gzgets($gzdata,4096))
    {
      fwrite($uncompressed_file,$line);

    }    
    log_message('debug','decompressed data '.$var);
    fclose($uncompressed_file);

    gzclose($gzdata);

    return $uncompressed_file;
```

i was trying to point out is that my method above was the method i used in overcoming in decompressing gzip data from the web and it turns out that it doesn't work do i need to configure something on my php or apache something? or do i need to install gz libraries to make it work? Need your professional advice and suggestions . Thank You

Another code Here: that i'm currently using:

```
    $chunkDecoded = base64_decode($data);
    //$decodeToJson = http_chunked_decode($chunkDecoded);
    //$zipCode =gzinflate(substr($chunkDecoded,10,-8));
    $zipCode = gzdecode($chunkDecoded);
    $decoded = json_decode($zipCode);
    log_message('debug','gzuncompress '.$decoded);
```

Comment: Dd you just want us to know you tried? You might want to explain what the problem is (if there is one).

Comment: @l'L'l  My sincerest apology i'm still new at stackoverflow what i was trying to point out is that my method above was the method i used in overcoming in decompressing gzip data from the web and it turns out that it doesn't work do i need to configure something on my php or apache something? or do i need to install gz libraries to make it work? Need your professional advice and suggestions . Thank You

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! Most people aren't going to take the time to debug your code, especially without specific information regarding the issue. You still haven't explained what the issue is (the error message, or undesired behavior, what does it do?) — "doesn't work" is too vague to tell us anything.

Comment: @l'L'l i just included my problem would that be ok or should i need to add something ? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "it is actually a data not a file"?

Comment: @l'L'l I've used the data from my mobile , the scenario is like this: From my android i needed to zipped the json data and send it by chunks now i've accomplish this thing now the counterpart to web server side is to decode the zipped and chunked data and put it in my database , How would i solve this? or any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: You need to say _what happens_. Did it give you an error? What error? Did it give you no error, but the data doesn't look right? What did you see that made you post this question?

Comment: @Mark Adler I haven't get an error but the data seems not right i've been playing along with the code and my algorithm goes like this from bas_64_decoded -> gz_decoded -> json_decoded and it doesnt ouput something , but as i ended up only gz_decode i get this thing "org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@3e583da8"

Comment: Since that's readable, it looks like the decompression worked perfectly.